# Can RVIZ send the camera image (with TF...) as a image topic?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm currently using the RVIZ camera display to visualize tf/Robotmodel/etc in my camera image. I'd like to show this combined view in a GUI. It would be very nice if I could get RVIZ to publish this topic on a normal image topic.
Has anyone done this before? I've so far not written my own plugin for RVIZ and hope that there is some easier way.

Cheers,
Nikolas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196413/can-rviz-send-the-camera-image-(with-tf...)-as-a-image-topic?/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2014-10-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think RViz can do that (directly).

Another option -- admittedly a bit more involved -- might be to use the visualisation bits of RViz (so not the GUI itself) directly in your GUI. See [Librviz Tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/librviz_tutorial/html/index.html).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1